# Jest test fails because of imported service from .ts file

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a Jest `.spec.js` file importing an `index.js` I want to test.

`.spec.js`:

```
var HttpService = require('./index.js').HttpService;
```

The issue is the following: that `index.js` file imports a `.ts` file that has errors in it. It does not seem to be an issue in the project (and I can't touch that .ts file) but `I get the errors from that .ts file when I run my jest test!`

`index.js`:

```
var service_factory = require('../service-factory.ts');
```

`service-factory.ts`:

```
import Loglevel from 'loglevel';
```

ERROR: `Cannot find module 'loglevel' or its corresponding type declarations`;

```
window.App.services
```

ERROR: `Property 'App' does not exist on type 'Window &typeof globalThis'`

I get exactly these errors when trying to run my test, referencing the `.ts file`..

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unusual for a .js file to import a .ts file. The error seems to be there. Js can only import typescript AFTER it's been transpiled to javascript. See if there's a .js file instead. If not you probably need to build it first. Looks exactly like an error from typescript being run as if it were JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot I think that is it! I guess the .ts is transpiled at run time in the project hence the index.js imports it. I'll see if I can convert it to .js or bypass it entirely (what it does might not be of interest for the testing).

Comment: More conventionally files are imported without suffixes like `import service_factory from '../service-factory';` , which points to a .ts file in a typescript-aware context (e.g. ts-node or ts-jest), and more typically points to a javascript file (at runtime when built). I wouldn't be surprised to see a jest setup in which typescript is never transpiled on disk, but is using e.g. ts-jest to transpile .ts source on the fly when needed. But I've not seen .ts as a suffix for an `import` and I would _never_ expect it in a `require()` from javascript.